# No Value given for one or more required parameters in Vb6

Tags: vb6

I'm new to Vb6.

I haven't inserted data in my database and when I run the program, an error shows ***No Value given for one or more required parameters***

Here's the code:

```
Dim list As ListItem, r As Integer
If recset.State = adStateOpen Then recset.Close

recset.Open "SELECT StudentId, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName FROM Students ORDER BY StudentId", rainCon, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

If recset.RecordCount > 1 Then
    MsgBox "No Data Found!", vbInformation, ""
Else
    ListView1.ListItems.Clear
    Do While Not recset.EOF
    
        r = r + 1
        
        Set list = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , r)
        list.SubItems(1) = recset(0).Value
        list.SubItems(2) = recset(1).Value
        list.SubItems(3) = recset(2).Value
        list.SubItems(4) = recset(3).Value
    
        recset.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```

Then highlights **recset.Open** part. How to control or fix this error?

Comment: How does your declaration of `recset` look like? I had instance in the past when I tabbed the `ADODB.Record` from IntelliSense instead of `ADODB.Recordset`.

Comment: Generally it just means you have an error in your SQL.  Since you aren't using parameters in your query, it usually indicates that one of the field names doesn't match the table.  Because of this, it interprets the unknown field as a parameter and gives you that message.

Comment: Is `Students` a table or query?

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to re-check my code and database multiple times. I found out that there was a missing attribute in my students table. The code was fully functional.

Answer (score -2):

**Find out the full working code.**

Private Sub cmdAddItemtoListBox_Click()

End Sub

> Change database path, name, and table as per your data.

[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwqvI.jpg)

```
Dim xCon    As New ADODB.Connection

Dim rsTable As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim StrSqlQuery As String

Dim Counter     As Integer

Dim list        As ListItem

If xCon.State = 1 Then xCon.Close
xCon.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Test\Test.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
'
StrSqlQuery = ""
StrSqlQuery = "Select * from Data Order by PrintSl"

If rsTable.State = 1 Then rsTable.Close
rsTable.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rsTable.Open StrSqlQuery, xCon, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

If rsTable.RecordCount > 0 Then
    rsTable.MoveFirst
    ListView1.ListItems.Clear
    ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add , , "ID"
    ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add , , "Customer Name"
    ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add , , "Address"
    ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add , , "Pincode"
    ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add , , "Amount"

    Do While Not rsTable.EOF
        Counter = ListView1.ListItems.Count + 1
        Set list = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , Counter)
        list.ListSubItems.Add , , rsTable!CUSTOMERNAME
        list.ListSubItems.Add , , rsTable!ADDRESS1
        list.ListSubItems.Add , , rsTable!pin
        list.ListSubItems.Add , , rsTable!LOAN_AMOUNT
        rsTable.MoveNext
    Loop
Else
    MsgBox "No record found in the table.", vbCritical

End If

If rsTable.State = 1 Then rsTable.Close
If xCon.State = 1 Then xCon.Close
MsgBox "Record Add Successfully", vbInformation
```

Comment: This does not appear to be answering the question.

Comment: @MarkL This is fully working and running code with proof of screenshot. What you are looking for as the answer.

Comment: Your example code appears to be for how to load a listview.  The OP asks a specific question about what is causing his SQL query (probably to an MS Access database) to fail and throw an error about missing parameters.  This answer does not address that question that I can see.

Comment: @MarkL The question does not contain any connection string details, without the connection details impossible detecting the error.  For this reason, I sent the user a fully working code.